# Dagger lateinit property has not been initialized when returning to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

What I'm trying to achieve is that `UserFragment` pops up a `DialogFragment`, the `DialogFragment` then uses a listener to notify the `UserFragment` of new user data.

When the `UserFragment` starts, `appDatabase` is being initialised and I can use it without any error. 
But when `DialogFragment` has been popped and it passes back data to `UserFragment` through a listener, using `appDatabase` makes the app crash with `UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appDatabase has not been initialized`. This is my sample code for injecting `appDatabase`

```
class UserFragment: DaggerFragment(), AddUserDialogFragment.DialogListener {

@Inject lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory
```

.....
}

Comment: Can you show where `appDatabase` is initialized? `DaggerFragment` does it's injection in `onAttach`, which may not have been called at the failing callsite.

Comment: It's been injected so Dagger should initialise it automatically I think

Answer (score 0):

Creating a clone of the `appDatabase` works for now. Like this.

```
@Inject lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase
@Inject lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory


private val clone by lazy {
    appDatabase
}
.....
```

While I am still waiting for a more elegant answer. Somehow I observed that `lateinit var appDatabase` is not longer available after calling `onPause()` and since we reenter the Fragment in `onResume()`, hence it's not calling `onAttach()` as @emerson noted that Dagger uses for dependency injection. 
I also had to pass the data to the fragment using `Bundle` instead of using listeners.